# Phonegap app/HTML

Tags: html, web-applications, cordova

I have an HTML app, not a native app. It's like a website, and I access a url with my mobile device, like a website. And geolocation doesn't work. It's a Phonegap app. I have: index.html, cordova-1.9.0.js, and two .js that contain the functions.

I posted my problem of not obtaining the coordinates on the Phonegap group of Google, and Simon Mac Donald answered me that I was doing it all wrong, but he was busy and told me that he would answer me later...

Now, I visit [my post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es&fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/ma5jlBmp2vg), but no updates. Could anyone explain to me a little?
Thanks very much, Daniel

Comment: No, because it isn't a native app. It's a html app. So, I have: index.html , cordova-1.9.0.js, and two .js files that contains some funtions to modify through jQuery the content of the divs...so, where should I modify the permissions?

Comment: that doesn't mean anything, aren't you lounching it like via java android project? In there you'll see an Android manifest, and in there you have to set your permissions.

Comment: No, I haven't installed anything in mobile device, it's like a website...I implemented like a website, in xampp, and uploaded it to a domain in production...and accessed through the mobile browser, to the url of the website(app).....So, I think I'm doing something wrong :(

Comment: You're confusing phonegap and websites. Phonegap is developed in HTML/JS, but it actually cross-compiles to produce native apps for most mobile OS. You'll need to deploy your app on the phone, not on a web server.

Comment: Hi Alexander, so I'll have to create my app in a android project, for example, in eclipse, and later export it as .apk, right? And I install this .apk file in my mobile device

Comment: @DanielGarcia Exactly. From what I've seen the documentation is pretty good, just follow it through.

Comment: Ammm, I thought that I could use phonegap like a framework, and upload the directory to a production, and access from my mobile to the url of production....

Comment: @DanielGarcia Unfortunately not. It *is* a framework, a framework for creating native HTML applications for a variety of mobile OS.

Comment: Yeah, I understand little by little. One question more: if I remove the link to the cordova.js of my index.html, and I continue using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition, when I access to the url with the browser of my mobile, it could works fine and obtain the coordinates, right? because these functions are part of the api of html5. Thanks Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is for native apps. You write code in HTML, Javascript and CSS, add a link to the cordova/phonegap.js file and ***then compile it*** to one of the supported platforms (iOS, Android, Winphone, etc). The end result is a native application.

You cannot use PhoneGap or any of its functionality in a web app.

Now, location services *can* be used in a web app because it is provided by all modern browsers. The object you need is `window.navigator.geolocation`. Here's a sample of how to use it (using `watchPosition()` based on your comment). Capturing `error` can help you track down why it's not working for you.

**Demo (code):** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/UZwdv/

**Demo (open on your phone):** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/UZwdv/show/

#### Script

```js
var location = document.getElementById( 'location' );

var geo = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( function ( position ) {
        location.textContent = position.coords.latitude  + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
    },
    function ( error ) {
        location.textContent = error.message;
    }
);

//later if you want to cancel it
window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( geo );
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="location"></div>​
```

Comment: Hi! But I have one question...In my case, I'm trying to obtain the coordinates each 1 second, in particular the speed. So, I use watchPosition for it...I read that navigator.geolocation.watchPosition is part of the api of html5, right? So, I could access to the speed of the mobile device, using html5, right?? I'll be grateful if you clarify me. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `watchPosition()` works the same way. I'll update to use that instead.

Comment: @DanielGarcia Note that `watchPosition()` updates on it's own schedule. It's not like it polls every second or anything.

Comment: So, one question. It isn't working because I include the cordova.js file in my index.html, and I try to access from the browser of my mobile, to the url, and phonegap doesn't work in this way.......if I remove the link to cordova.js from my index.html, then accessing to the url from the browser of my mobile it'll works, right? because this is part of html5.

Comment: @DanielGarcia Yes, completely remove anything phonegap/cordova related.

Comment: I have this code: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);</br>

    var watchID = null;</br>
 
 // PhoneGap ha cargado -> Llamada al objeto geolocation para localizar el dispositivo por GPS
 function onDeviceReady() {</br>
        // Throw an error if no update is received every 1 seconds
        var options = { timeout: 1000, enableHighAccuracy: true };</br>
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }`    </br>     So, with **timeout:1000** it will update each one second,right?

Comment: Ahhhh ok ok!! I understand...I was making impossible to html5 functions work fine because I was overriding with api of phonegap, but api of phonegap wasn't working because isn't for web apps, right? **Thanks very much friend I'm very gratefull with you**

Comment: @DanielGarcia No, the `timeout` is how long it tries to get a location before throwing an error.

Comment: **Another important question** Testing it in Ripple extension of Chrome, and editing the coordinates, speed, and these...it works fine! I link to cordova.js in index.html, and it won't work, right? I don't understand why it works testing with Ripple

Comment: @DanielGarcia I'm not familiar with Ripple, sorry.

Comment: It's a extension of chrome, that allow test a url in some mobile devices. It allows you choosing the mobile device of a list, and play with some functions of geolocation